Why do certain git installations forget commands entered while the previous command is evaluating?
On certain git installations, this happens:

If I enter command B (e.g. echo foo) in git bash while command A (e.g. sleep 3) is evaluating, command B will evaluate afterwards:

user@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 /c/Dev/Repos/myrepo (mybranch)
$ sleep 3
echo foo

user@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 /c/Dev/Repos/myrepo (mybranch)
$ echo foo
foo

user@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 /c/Dev/Repos/myrepo (mybranch)
$


If I hit tab to autocomplete a branch name, I can keep typing/tabbing/entering while autocomplete is executing and it will work, with the same result as if I waited to do all that after autocomplete finished.

On other installations, I get the following behavior:

A command entered while another is evaluating is lost.

user@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 /c/Dev/Repos/myrepo (mybranch)
$ sleep 3
echo foo

user@COMPUTERNAME MINGW64 /c/Dev/Repos/myrepo (mybranch)
$

(It still works fine if I type the second command but do not enter until the first command is done.)

Any typing/tabbing/entering during autocomplete is lost.

What causes the latter behavior? How do I fix it?
The former behavior is seen on my git installation at home (2.44.0.windows.1) and various older installations at work (2.30.0.windows.2, 2.39.2.windows.1), while the latter behavior is seen on newer git installations at work (2.44.0.windows.1 and some 2.43 version we used to have).

I am not really sure of the cause but I would guess stdin is being consumed somehow and that is thy the command that you write while the sleep is running is not executed after it finishes.

You seem to be on Windows, which is often an ample explanation for things not working like they should.
